# NotificationListenerService when app closed

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

I am trying to implement the NotificationListenerService functionality and I managed to make it work well. But when I close the app it stops.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String allowReadNotification = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners");
        if (allowReadNotification == null || !allowReadNotification.contains(getPackageName())){
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
        }
    }

}
```

```xml
<service
            android:name=".NotificationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

```java
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        Log.i("LOG", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String title = "";
        String text = "";


        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
            title = extras.getCharSequence("android.title").toString();
            text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

            Log.i("LOG",pack);
            Log.i("LOG",title);
            Log.i("LOG",text);
            Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
    }
}
```

would anyone tell me how to keep this service running and display Toast even with the app closed?